# Pig Error : Failed to Parse Query

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, grunt-shell

I am trying to write a filter UDF , which will take input as Tuple , and return tuple, but when i DEFINE the function in Gruntt shell I am getting the error msg as failed to parse , where i am doing it wrong here

```
 REGISTER /home/filterUDF.jar;

 DEFINE filDist  'FilterDistrictUdf/FilterDistrict' 


package FilterDistrictUdf;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;

import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;


public class FilterDistrict extends FilterFunc{

@Override
public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    String line = input.toString();
    String[] columns = line.split(",");
    Double bplObjective = Double.parseDouble(columns[2]);
    Double bplPerformance = Double.parseDouble(columns[10]);



    //Double bplObjective = (Double )input.get(2);
    //Double bplPerformance = (Double )input.get(10);
    //BigInteger mul = new BigInteger("80");
    //BigInteger div = new BigInteger("100");

    if(bplPerformance >= ( (bplObjective* 80)/100) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;


}
```

}

Error :

```
  ERROR 1200: <line 40, column 15>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or 
  near ''FilterDistrictUdf/FilterDistrict''

  Failed to parse: <line 40, column 15>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at 
  or near ''FilterDistrictUdf/FilterDistrict''
   at 

  org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:244)
   at 
  org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:182)
   at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1707)
   at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1680)
   at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:623)
   at 
   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1063)
   at
```

org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:558)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at

sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
      va:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming when i was trying to

```
   DEFINE filDist  'FilterDistrictUdf/FilterDistrict'
```

Instead of defining temporay function filDist , tried using the function directly in filter operator as

```
    chk1 = FILTER elements by FilterDistrictUdf.FilterDistrict(*)
```

and it worked properly